# unnesting array to columns in trino/athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a column on my athena table which looks like so:

```
id, authors
123,[{institutions=[<more_content>], author={name="james"}}, {institutions=[<more content>], author={name="john"}}]
245,[]
765,[{institutions=[<more_content>], author={name="mike"}}, {institutions=[<more content>], author={name="peter"}}]
```

Id like this exploded table from this:

```
id, author_row_number,name
123,1,james
123,2,john
765,1,mike
765,2,peter
```

where `author_row_number` is the index within the row.
How do I go about achieving this in Athena Trino please

Comment: Can you please add the result of `select typeof(authors) from ...`  query?

Answer (score 0):

Usually such output is shown for either row or dictionary types. Depending on the Athena engine version and actual type there can be variability but assuming that you have an array one of those two the main trick would be using `UNNEST` combined with the `WITH ORDINALITY` clause (see [the docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest)). Something along these lines (assuming the type of `ARRAY(ROW(...))` and engine v.3 based on Trino which will unpack row into separate columns, not tested):

```sql
select id,
   t.author_row_number,
   t.author.name name
from table,
unnest(authors) WITH ORDINALITY as t(institutions, author, author_row_number)
```